# PHP invoke Scanner Hardware and scan documents and upload it to Server

Tags: php, upload, document, invoke, scanning

How to invoke Scanner from php script and scan document and then upload scanned document to server ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [phpSANE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/).

> phpSANE is a web-based frontend for SANE written in HTML/PHP so you can scan with your web-browser. It also supports OCR.

Comment: Looks like dead project (Last Update: 2013-10-24).